# Calling SOAP web service from VoiceXML

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, vxml

I've searched until my Google was sore, but there doesn't seem to be a huge amount of information out there on consuming a web service from within VXML. There are a few examples (such as from the W3C), but I haven't been able to get any of them to work and I'm afraid I'm just grinding metal at this point.

Can someone help me with a simple example of how to call a web service from within VXML? I know that the  tag was introduced with 2.1 and it seems that this is where I should be directing my attention, but I'm just not getting any traction.

I've been trying to use this sample web service as a simple foundation: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Unfortunately, we're not well equipped to handle such a broad question. As you may know, the SO documentation project recently went bust, but it would have been a good place to answer this.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you will be able to make a SOAP call from VoiceXML. The Data element sends key/value pairs in either an http GET or POST request. While you could put the XML for the soap request in the variable value, the variable name will also be sent causing an XML parse error.

To call SOAP services, the typical approach is to have an intermediate application tier to receive the data element request, convert it to SOAP, receive the SOAP response, clean up the result so the VoiceXML application doesn't have to do so much parsing (simple XML data structure

Comment: Some interpreter like Voximal add those Soap intagration with the tag <object>. Object is the best way to extend the standard VoiceXML interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Some VoiceXML interpreter extend the main VoiceXML functionalities by offering new connectors (of of the standard).
In the case of Voximal for example, there are two extensions :
 -  : enable to use JSON / XML / Text / param=value(INI) requests
 -  : enable CURL and SOAP requests with specific plugins.

Have a look to your documentation, if not the only solution is to develop a  / SOAP web service...